# How to add combobox to second column in datagriview in c# wiforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to add combobox to particular column in datagridview . I am add a combobox not( DataGridViewComboBoxColumn) .

Comment: Welcome to SO. So we can help you, can you post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: try this [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tA8RNb_Sd_I]

Answer (score 1):

You can only add this Types:

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
DataGridViewLinkColumn
DataGridViewImageColumn
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
DataGridViewButtonColumn
```

Why you want add a `ComboBox`?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem and handled it like this if my memory serves me correctly was a long time ago, not the best way of doing things but it worked.

```
private void mainGrid_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Column.Name != "Name of your combobox column")
     return;

     ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
     cb.Bounds = e.CellBounds;
     cb.Font = ((mainGrid)sender).Font;
     cb.DataSource = "Your Datasource";
     cb.DisplayMember = "your display members";
     cb.ValueMember = "your value members";
     e.Control = cb;
}
```